# Using Bot Framework, all chat messages need to be proxied through Microsoft servers?

Tags: bots, botframework

Until now I have developed bots using each platform API directly, so that communication takes place between my bot and the platform like this:

   `My Bot <----> Telegram/Slack servers`

I would like to use BotBuilder SDK to simplify bot development and unify communication to multiple Bot platforms (Telegram, Slack, etc.).
However, it looks like using BotBuilder also implies using Microsoft servers as an intermediary relaying all chat messages between each platform and my bot:

   `My Bot <----> Microsoft servers <----> Telegram/Slack servers`

Is it like this? Using BotBuilder SDK messages need to be proxied through Microsoft servers?

(I expected that the BotBuilder SDK library would directly provide the features of adapting message format (between the unified format and each platform/channel format) and communicating with each platform API, but it looks like this is really done by Microsoft servers.)

If this is really the case, which components would need to be reimplemented/overriden to be able to communicate directly with each platform REST API? The Bot Connector service? Is there any example available? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's the Bot Connector role and it's not open-source